# UITextField copyable but not editable Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield, ios8

I have a `UITextField` in my Swift iOS app. How do I make it copyable, but not editable?

Here's what I've tried:

1. Setting "User Interaction Enabled" to on. The field is copyable, but if one touches it, a keyboard pops up.
2. Setting "User Interaction Enabled" to off. No keyboard, but not copyable.

What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `UITextView` instead of `UITextField`. `UITextField` does not have an `isEditable` property. The following Swift 5 code shows a possible implementation of a `UITextView` instance that matches your requirements:

```
textView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
textView.isEditable = false
```

According to the documentation, [`isUserInteractionEnabled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622577-isuserinteractionenabled) determines whether user events are ignored and removed from the event queue and [`isEditable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextview/1618616-iseditable) indicates whether the receiver is editable.

Comment: OP is asking about a UITextField, not a UITextView. UITextField does not have an `editable` property.

Comment: textField.enabled = NO;